# Permissions required for deploying wsp files and debugging workflows

Tags: workflow, permissions, wspbuilder, solution-deployment

I am having issues at a client with regards to permissions that I need to  request for my account to be able to deploy wsps (using WSPBuilder) to the development environment, and to debug workflows in SharePoint 2007:

As far as I know the following are the required permissions:

- Farm Administrator
- Site Collection Administrator
- Member of the "local Administrators" group on each server in the farm (excluding DB)
- Member of the DB_owner role on the SharePoint_Config DB and the content DBs for the Central Admin and web applications.

Any other permissions required, or any on this list that are not required ?

Comment: Is SharePoint on the same machine that you're running VS on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the system administrators didn't apply the rights correctly at a DB level. We got them to provide the correct rights and I can now deploy and debug.

Answer (score 0):

To debug all you need is to be farm administrator and site collection administrator then attach the debugger and you are ready to go.

RUn as admin vs 2010 or vs 2008

Comment: The problem is that the account they provisioned for me has Farm and site collection admin rights, but when trying to debug it just gives access denied errors in VS 2008.

Comment: @MrThirsty So the solution deployed ok? Maybe including a screenshot in your question would help..

Comment: I can't deploy anything either, when I run WSPBuilder to deploy the wsp solution, it says that my account doesn't have installation permissions on the server. trying to debug existing solutions deployed by the previous developer.

Comment: Have you tried 'Run as Administrator' on VS?

Comment: I can't "Run as admin" as I am using Win Server 2003, which only gives you a "Run As" option, you need to know the administrator password. Which I do not know.